# How to create a dynamic persistent volume claim with ReadWriteMany access in GKE?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, persistent-volumes

Currently GCEPersistentDisk does not support ReadWriteMany natively, there are other options like filestore which creates a NFS volume, but there are 2 problem here:

1. minimum 1 TB size is needed to be created
2. secondly its a manually effort of creating PVs and then PVCs

Whats the best solutions for dynamically allocating a claim request in GKE ?

Comment: https://medium.com/@Sushil_Kumar/readwritemany-persistent-volumes-in-google-kubernetes-engine-a0b93e203180#:~:text=Persistent%20Volumes%20in%20GKE%20are,by%20many%20nodes)%20access%20modes.

Comment: Thanks @HarshManvar, Ive already taken a look at the post, but we need dynamic allocation of PVCs.

Comment: for that you can create the storage class and create the dynamic provision with NFS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have requirement of dynamic provising with you can alos try using the [Gluster](https://www.gluster.org/) FS or [Minio](https://min.io/).

here is one nice example using the GlusterFS dynamic provisioning : https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.9/install_config/storage_examples/gluster_dynamic_example.html

you have to create the **storageclass**

```
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: glusterfs
provisioner: kubernetes.io/glusterfs
parameters:
  resturl: "http://10.42.0.0:8080" 
  restauthenabled: "false"
```

and create the **PVC** with specific **storageclass**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: gluster1
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 30Gi
  storageClassName: glusterfs
```

Also, **You can create Filestore file shares between 1 and 63.9 TiB**
and **dynamic provisioning**:  https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/gke-filestore-dynamic-provisioning