# Persistent volume claim attach to kubernetes deployment to access files present in PVC but should not write any logs to PVC?

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, google-kubernetes-engine, nginx-ingress, kubernetes-pvc

I have a requirement to store files in a PVC and attach that PVC to a Nginx ingress controller deployment so that application can access the files which are present in PVC but at the same application should not write back logs and configurations to PVC.

Can you please let me know how can i achieve it?

I Created a PVC and attached it a deployment but it is writing logs and configurations to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [GCP fuse](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gcs-fuse) and **store** files to **S3** directly that way it would be a little easy to manage if it's works for you.

However, if you want to go with your Idea you have to implement the **ReadWriteMany** ([Read More](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57798369/5525824)). So **two** **POD** can attach to one **PVC** and one write and the other one read.

You can also use the EFS, or NFS file systems [GKE with Filestore](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/gke-filestore-dynamic-provisioning) from GCP or [MinIO](https://min.io/), [GlusterFS](https://www.gluster.org/).

[Ref answer glusterfs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68586922/5525824)

> I Created a PVC and attached it a deployment but it is writing logs
> and configurations to it.

```
volumeMounts:
          - name: file
            mountPath: /var/data
            readOnly: true
```

You can set the **mode** when mounting the file or directory and set it as **read-only** mode also `readOnly: true`.

Comment: Hi @Harsh , Thank you so much for the detailed explanation. we have deployed Kong as Ingress Controller in our clusters, how can i use GCP fuse for already running kong because we want to use those files for building custom plugins.

Also, we might use it for already deployed applications, so i need to have installed fuse in those applications at the time of building docker image right?

Comment: Ahaan..! Kong is good choice with the plugins..! might be helpful : https://github.com/ael-computas/gcp-kubernetes-bucket-nfs-server